# Google+ brand display in SERPs

Tags: google, google-search, search-results, google-plus, google-plus-pages

Until very recent past, when someone searched for our brand name on Google, our G+ page preview with latest post showed up on the sidebar of SERPs.

However, it has just disappeared and we have checked that rel=publisher tags are implemented in SERPs correctly.

We have had a lot of activity on the Google+ page recently and if anything, Google would have improved our display.

Is it possible that Google is thinking that increased activity on our G+ page is spam??

Answer (score 1):

having rel publisher tags does not guarantee google will show the brand associated with the Google+ brand page.

Few things you want to check.
1. Make sure you have not recently chosen and new URL for your google+ page (changing from # to something custom). 
2. Make sure that this is happening when you request the raw page.  Actually type the full url in search and see what is happening.

ALternativly you can use Google's new markup for RichSnippets and include Organization details:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146861?hl=en

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"> 
   <span itemprop="name">L'Amourita Pizza</span> 
   Located at 
   <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      <span itemprop="streetAddress">123 Main St</span>,
      <span itemprop="addressLocality">Albuquerque</span>,
      <span itemprop="addressRegion">NM</span>.
   </div>
  <img itemprop="logo" src="http://www.example.com/logo.png" />
   Phone: <span itemprop="telephone">206-555-1234</span>
   <a href="http://pizza.example.com/" itemprop="url">http://pizza.example.com</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon further investigation, it seems like a bug with Google plus. http://searchengineland.com/google-loses-real-estate-search-brand-boxes-dropped-logged-users-203567

Comment: You should probably still try and include the schema.org brand snippet, because other search engines are more likely to grab it from that versus getting it from Google+.  Having both probably will not hurt.